# pyobjc-framework-Quartz 6.2.2 installation in my local machine failed

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

this is the error message:-

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\subha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\subha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fzue6kqx\\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\subha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fzue6kqx\\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\subha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-l2txi8lf'
     cwd: C:\Users\subha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzue6kqx\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzue6kqx\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    Extension(
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzue6kqx\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\pyobjc_setup.py", line 420, in Extension
    if "clang" in get_config_var("CC"):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

i'm using python 3.8 with pip version 20.1.1.

Comment: Any `pyobjc`-related project is intended only for MacOS X. You cannot install it at Windows.

Comment: Any alternate for windows